# how to maintain display order field in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to maintain one integer field  in database for display order,which will be unique(obvious)

now lets say I have 10 records in database, and if I will update 10th record and will set display order from 10 to 1, so all records from 1 to 9 will increment bye one,like 
display order 1 will become 2, 2 to 3,3 to 4, 4 to 5 ....

so how to maintain this?

wants any optimize solution, if we have 1000's record then we can not fire update query for all 999 records.

**Please help me**

Comment: why You want to create display_order column in DB?

Comment: lets say suppose i am posting products on my site,i have 10 product,and want to change display order ,so for this i will use my this field "displayorder"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try with **function or stored procedure**.. these two are enough cool to handle such situations.. lets give a try to below one.. hope it will help you out..

Remember I am considering following two parameters

```
table name - DisplayOrder
column name to reorder = O_nbr
```

if you need to shift the O_nbr (order number) from 10 to 1 you just need to call the method as

```
select UpdateOrder(10,1);
// it will return you the proper message either updated or not.. or whatever
```

the function code is as below -

```
DELIMITER $$
create function UpdateOrder (fromOrder int, toOrder int) 
RETURNS varchar(50)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  DECLARE reslt varchar(50);
  DECLARE rowCount int;
  SET reslt = 'Error Occured.';
  if( fromOrder < 1) then
    SET reslt='fromOrder can not be less then 1';
  elseif(toOrder < 1) then
    SET reslt='toOrder can not be less then 1';
  else  
    select count(*) into rowCount from DisplayOrder;        
    if(rowCount < fromOrder) then
        SET reslt = concat('Sorry check again, we have only ',rowCount, ' records');
    elseif(rowCount < toOrder) then
        SET reslt = concat('Sorry check again, we have only ',rowCount, ' records');
    else
        if(fromOrder = toOrder) then
            SET reslt = 'No Changes were made.';
        else
            if(fromOrder > toOrder) then
              update DisplayOrder set O_nbr = 0 where O_nbr = fromOrder;
              Update DisplayOrder set O_nbr = O_nbr+1 where O_nbr < fromOrder AND O_nbr > (toOrder-1) order by O_nbr desc;
              update DisplayOrder set O_nbr = toOrder where O_nbr = 0;
            end if;
            if(fromOrder < toOrder) then
              update DisplayOrder set O_nbr = 0 where O_nbr = fromOrder;
              Update DisplayOrder set O_nbr = O_nbr-1 where O_nbr > fromOrder AND O_nbr < (toOrder+1) order by O_nbr asc;
              update DisplayOrder set O_nbr = toOrder where O_nbr = 0;
            end if;
            SET reslt = 'Successfully done';
        end if;
    end if;         
  end if;     
  RETURN reslt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You can replace the **DisplayOrder** with you table nane and **O_nbr** with you column name to reorder

copy the code and run it in you mysql database query window.. then to shift the order (**O_nbr in DisplayOrder table**) use the above described signature..

```
Select UpdateOrder(fromOrder,  toOrder);
```

if you try to run with 0 or less value, or any unsuitable condition, it will return you the error message

```
Select UpdateOrder(10, 0);
//returns "toOrder can not be less then 1"
Select UpdateOrder(11, 1);
//return "Sorry check again, we have only 10 records"
Select UpdateOrder(5, 5);
//returns "No Changes were made."
```

if you pass the correct parameter..

```
Select UpdateOrder(10, 2);
//returns "Successfully done"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use bigger values for display, like say :

```
apple : 1 000 000

orange : 2 000 000

banana : 3 000 000
```

Now if I want to add `potato` in position 2 (n=2) I take n (=> 2 : orange) and (n-1)(=> 1 : apple) position and divide them by 2 to get the new potato position :

(1 000 000 + 2 000 000) / 2

= 1 500 000

```
apple : 1 000 000

**potato : 1 500 000**

orange : 2 000 000

banana : 3 000 000
```

This will work a pretty long time, and if at some point you feel like you've exhausted this schema, you can still multiply all values by 1000.

You may as well keep using low value (1, 2, 3, ...) and define their type as `DOUBLE`, so they will never collide when dividing them by 2.

**EDIT :** About placing banana in position 1 :

Using formula (n+(n-1))/2:

Here n = 1 (new position).

Our data is :

```
apple : 1 000 000

potato : 1 500 000

orange : 2 000 000

banana : 3 000 000
```

(1 000000+(0))/2

= 500 000

I give the order 500 000 to banana :

```
**banana : 500 000**

apple : 1 000 000

potato : 1 500 000

orange : 2 000 000
```

---

Yet another solution : create a text field that would be an indexer and contain all ids.

"1,2,3,4,5,6,7"

Now If I want to put element id 8 between 3 and 4, I simply have to replace ",4," by ",8,4,".

Though it's more complicated in terms of computing to find element at index n so I'd personnaly use the first solution.

Comment: what if i want banana on first position here?

Comment: (0 + 1000000) / 2 => 500 000

Comment: means? please can you explain bit more ?

Comment: What do you want me to elaborate? When you have defined a display value using the formula above, simply order your rows on this field, and you are good.

Answer (score 0):

You can display data in any order without changing the `id` field value in the database.
I don't think it would be necessary to show the value of `ID` to the end user, but use only for internal reference.

You can try like this:

```
select * from my_table
order by field( id, 10 ), id asc
```

This causes to fetch row with `id` value `10` on top and others next in `ascending` order.

You can specify any number of values in `field` to show in that specific order on top of results.