# Order of elements referenced by Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, software-design

I‘m thinking about a good DB design for this use case:

- Table `topics`
- Table `articles` with foreign key `topic_id`
- Right now, each article belongs to one topic. In future versions, I might change that, so that one article belongs to many topics.

Now I want to maintain the order of articles for each topic. In which Table should I store this Information: topics, articles or a third one?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of articles - topics links are variable, you need a link table.

So:

```
Table Articles
    idArticles   PK, int, auto-increment, not null
    Title        varchar, not null

Table Topics
    idTopics     PK, int, auto-increment, not null
    Title        varchar, not null

Table Topics-have-Articles
    idTopics     PK, FK to Topics:idTopics, not null
    idArticles   PK, FK to Articles:idArticles, not null
    Order        int, not null
```

Notes:

- PK: primary key
- FK: foreing key
- In Topics-have-Articles, the PK is (idTopics,idArticles)
- You say you want to maintain order of articles inside a topic.  At first, I had put a date value.  Based on your comment I modified it to an int value (Order).  You can then setup an application page to take care of this ordering.
- If you stay with a 1 to 1 relationship for the time being, this will still work, but allows you to easily transition to n to 1, or n to m relations.

Potential problems with the order field:

- lets say you order your articles 1,2,3,4,5.  What happens if you want to put one between 4 and 5?  You have to reorder them all.
- lets say you order 10,20,30,40.  Then you have 10 "slots" to put new articles in between, but you will run out eventually.
- this might not be a problem if your application is small.  But you might have to write some code to reorder your articles on insert.
- That might warrant another search in SO, like this one: [how to maintain display order field in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243740/how-to-maintain-display-order-field-in-php)

Comment: Thanks! I want to assign a custom order (int position?) and I want to able to re-order them manually.

Comment: I edited my answer with an order `int` instead of the `Date` field.

Comment: I blogged on efficient list handling years ago:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/lists

Comment: @RickJames indeed, good post, it is a good solution to consider.

Answer (score 1):

So if in the future you want to have many topics for one article and, i supose that one topic may have many articles, you will need a third table.
If you are going to have only one topic for an article, you should insert it in the table article, one column for topic_id.

This will be a many-to-many relation so you need a third table with the id of the topic and the and the id of the article. The primary key will be (topic_id,article_id) so you only have one combination of article-topic. In this table both, topic_id and article_id are foreign keys.